# How do I register a style in the React div?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
<div className="Stars" style="--rating: 6.8">{movie.vote_average}</div>
```

How do I set the style in the React div, I have the value stars:before to display the rating how do I set the style correctly in the div?

Comment: Style attribute is an object in React so `style={{ '--rating': 6.8 }}`

Comment: Thanks! its great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div className="Stars" style={{"--rating": "6.8" }}>{movie.vote_average}</div>
```